# lift import net.liftweb returns an error "not found: value net"

Tags: scala, import, lift

I'm new with scala and lift but I already got the pocketchangeapp up
and running and playing around with the RestAPI thing in it.
Now I created a new project and it worked quite well until last night.
I made my latest changes and commited them in svn but hat a problem
with my workspace so I deleted my projects and did a checkout of the
Project in svn.
Since I did that my imports of net.liftweb._ (any classes also if I
write the exact class name) only return an error in eclipse:

import net.liftweb._     gives me "not found: value net"

I checked again all dependencies in the pom.xml but I cannot find the
error.
Help would be great, thank you.
Michael

Answer (score 0):

I got it...
I had to reconfigure Build Path and add the lift dependencies so the maven dependencies showed up again. After that I had to edit every single file and save it again to make my imports work!

Comment: Would you be so kind to explain the fix with some details?

Comment: I would like to know. I have this error right now. Looking for solutions!