# Configgy import fails in lift

Tags: scala, logging, lift

I was trying to use Configgy for logging in my Lift project and I added

```
lazy val configgy = "net.lag" % "configgy" % "2.0.0" intransitive()
```

to my Plugins.scala. Then I import the needed classes like this:

```
import net.lag.logging.Logger
```

Then I use the Logger in Boot.scala. But when I compile I get the following error:

```
value lag is not a member of package net
```

Why is that? The jar is on the classpath, everything should be in place. 
I'm using Scala 2.8.1, Lift 2.3 and SBT 2.7.5.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `import _root_.net.lag.logging.Logger`

Comment: Yes, I also tried this but the result was the same. BTW, I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083409/lift-import-net-liftweb-returns-an-error-not-found-value-net) to a very similar question but the solution is not really obvious.